# Caching NuGet packages on VSO's Host Agent Pool

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, nuget-package-restore, dnu

When running on builds in VSO's new host agent pool, I have a powershell script to restore the NuGet packages for each `project.json` using `dnu restore`.

This process can easily take more than 2 minutes.

Is it not possible to somehow cache these packages on the agent? Would this only be possible if we had our own custom agent?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you're right that you need to set up one on-premise TFS build controller and agent to avoid restoring NuGet packages each time when you build projects.

NuGet package restore will install all referenced packages before a project is built, it is possible for you to cache packages on on-premise build agent but not on hosted build agent.

Comment: It's worth explicitly noting that when you run on a hosted build agent, you are always getting a different build agent. Thus, nothing is cached between builds.

Answer (score 1):

In VSTS (cloud), *NuGet Restore* task allows you to use NuGet packages from the machine. I have tried this and it cuts on the time it takes to restore all packages.

[image: Setting in NuGet Restore Task]